# pfSense Captive Portal on devices that cannot use login page(STBs, etc.)

Tags: networking, firewall, authentication, pfsense, captive-portal

I am using captive portal with pfSense on a network in order to filter content and monitor bandwidth, etc. This has worked great with computers and mobile devices in the office as everyone has been able to login every day with their specified login credentials. However, with devices like the occasional Verizon FiOS set top boxes, they are not able to access internet services because pfSense cannot serve the login page to these devices (there is no browser on the STB). Has anyone had this issue before, and if so how was it fixed? My last resort would be to pass them through the firewall no matter what, but I would like to avoid that if possible for security reasons.

Gary

Comment: Could you create some paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PFSense captive portal supports [MAC bypass](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal#Pass-Through_MAC_Tab).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. I'm hoping if there is no other way for the devices to login, at least it might still collect bandwidth data on the bypassed devices. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's a completely separate topic from what you asked about.